# Using std::hex to convert hex to decimal

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working with VS 2010 on Windows. I have a function which takes a `char` pointer. Now, inside the function, I am calling `std::hex` to convert it to decimal, but for some reason it is not working. It is outputting a large value which makes me think that it is converting the address instead.

```
void convertHexToDec(char* hex, char * dec)
{
    long long decimal;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << hex;
    ss >> std::hex >> decimal;

    sprintf (dec, "%llu", decimal);
}
```

So, if the pass in a `char` pointer containing `"58"`, the output decimal value is something like `1D34E78xxxxxxxxx`. Looks like it is converting the address of the hex.

I tried these ways too:

```
ss << *hex;

ss << (char*)hex[0];

ss << (int *)&hex[0];
```

None of the above worked.

Any idea how I can make this function work?

Comment: What is wrong with strtol?

Comment: @donguy76 `%llu` is for **unsigned** `long long`.  Use `d` instead of `u` for a **signed** `long long`, which is what you actually have.  Also, do some error checking to make sure that `ss >> std::hex >> decimal` is not failing before you call `sprintf()`.

Comment: @ZDF the fact that it is C, has an ambiguous error indicator that clashes with a valid value, and is not what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is, probably, the wrong `printf` specifier. Also, `sprintf` is **not safe**: it assumes the destination buffer (`dec`) is large enough.

A possible solution using your function signature - not recommended since you do not know the size of the destination:

```
void convertHexToDec( char* hex, char * dec )
{
  std::sprintf( dec, "%lld", std::strtoll( hex, 0, 16 ) );
}
```

A safe solution:

```
std::string convertHexToDec( const char* h )
{
  return std::to_string( std::strtoll( h, 0, 16 ) );
}
```

A safe solution using streams:

```
std::string convertHexToDec( const char* h )
{
  long long lld;
  std::istringstream( h ) >> std::hex >> lld;

  std::ostringstream os;
  os << lld;

  return os.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from you not using `std::string` and refrences, I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void convertHexToDec(char* hex, char* dec)
{
    long long decimal;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << hex;
    ss >> std::hex >> decimal;
    std::cout << "Decimal: " << decimal << "\n";

    sprintf (dec, "%llu", decimal);
}

int main()
{
    char hex[] = "58";
    char dec[4];

    convertHexToDec(hex, dec);

    std::cout << "Output string: " << dec << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Decimal: 88
Output string: 88
```

[live example](http://rextester.com/MBC48474)

So what's your problem?

Comment: Would be more clear if we showed the input string and labeled it hex, and then showed the output string and labeled it decimal. But yea, I don't see the problem either. Maybe the op confused himself with what he chose to write to std out.

Comment: The problem was with the hex char pointer getting corrupted in the function that was calling my convertHexToDec.

Comment: @donguy76 "is getting corrupted". Is that a new phrase for "I made a programming mistake" ? ;) Next time please include a [mcve].